# I am trying to create a trigger for creating a new lead when the account name on the contact changes

Tags: apex

I am trying to create a trigger for creating a new lead when the account name on the contact changes. But the trigger is copying all other data except the Account name and it is showing

> **Missing Field: Company**

Can any body help?

```
trigger concot on Contact (before update){ 
    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){ 
     Map<Id,Contact> mymap = Trigger.newMap; 
     List<Lead> li = new list <Lead>();
     List<Contact> lu =[select id,phone,Contact.FirstName,Contact.LastName,Account.Name,MailingAddress,
                         Email,Fax,Title
                         from Contact
                         where id in:mymap.keyset()];

      for(Contact c:lu){
        Lead l = new Lead();
        l.FirstName = c.FirstName;
        l.LastName = c.LastName;
        l.Company = mymap.get(c.id).Account.Name;
        l.phone = mymap.get(c.id).phone;
        // l.Address = mymap.get(c.id).MailingAddress;  
        l.Email = mymap.get(c.id).Email; 
        l.Title = mymap.get(c.id).Title;
        l.Fax = mymap.get(c.id).Fax;
        li.add(l);
      }

    insert li;   
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set this up pretty easily with a Process Builder.

Set Process Builder to "Contact".

Criteria --> When Account is Changed

Action --> Record Create... 1) create Lead.  2) update Lead w/ fields from the contact (easily done via Reference in a Process Builder).  3) Update the Account Name via diving into the Account Id > value and grabbing the Account field "Name".

Shouldn't need to do any code with this!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in trigger you have to understand below line will give null only.

```
l.Company = mymap.get(c.id).Account.Name;
```

Since you are directly using the trigger.newMap, you will have only accountID in trigger.newMap. If you need to get any other field in account, you need to query that separately(in your case `account.Name`).

Updated code

You can try like below. But, you will need to make further updates to make sure that, if matching leads are created already, your trigger is not creating duplicate leads again in every edit.

```
trigger concot on Contact (before update){ 
    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){ 
     List<Lead> li = new list <Lead>();
      List<Contact> lu =[select id,phone,Contact.FirstName,Contact.LastName,Account.Name,MailingAddress,
                         Email,Fax,Title
                         from Contact
                         where id in:mymap.keyset()];

      for(Contact c:lu){

         Lead l = new Lead();

        l.FirstName = c.FirstName;
        l.LastName = c.LastName;
        l.Company = c.Account.Name;
        l.phone = c.phone;
        // l.Address = c.MailingAddress;  
         l.Email = c.Email; 
         l.Title = c.Title;
         l.Fax = c.Fax;
        li.add(l);
      }

    insert li;   
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . can you elaborate more?

Comment: Above code will work. But you need to add additional code to make sure that, you are not creating duplicates for each edit.

Comment: Hi victor I tried this approach but this is helping only when I am trying to create the same contact as lead but i want to create a new lead whenever the account name changes .This is a lead with the same information. The new lead should contain the new Account name.

Comment: How we can set address to Lead ?